# When will child element affect the position of parent element?

Tags: html, css

I put a `<img>` element into a `<div>` element. I suppose the `<img>` just to be there, but it changed the position of the `<div>` element.

A simplified structure of my HTML:

```
<div class="box" id="box6">
<img src="circle-shape-outline.svg">

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #364F6B;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;

    width: 32.9%;
    height: 33%;
 }

div#box6 {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix it? You can have a look at the complete code on [codePen](http://codepen.io/luiyezheng/pen/KMKgRM) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<div>`s have `display: inline-block` so when you add an `<img>` it tries to adjust the image to the bottom of current row.

You can set `float: left` on the image or set `position: relative` on  `#box6` and then `position: absolute` on `<img>` to position in wherever you want inside the div.

Answer (score 1):

add `display:block;` style for your image element. to align `center` use `margin:0 auto`. It will work.
This is output

[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04wf4ubj/)

Comment: Sorry but if you will add only display:block, it won't work.

Comment: Do you even get idea what op wants?? check your own fiddle and then post it plz.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your image borders are displacing and increasing the size of the div. I would try setting the size of the image to the size of your box using the stretch command after image source.

Comment: Could you provide more detail?:-)

Comment: I would try changing the HTML to <img src="circle-shape-outline.svg" class="stretch"> I'm thinking that this should resize the image to the parent div. From there you could add a margin and hide the overlap if necessary to get the bubble positioned correctly.